# Why do my screen colours change when I plug in the charger?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, macbook-pro-retina, macos-mojave

https://youtu.be/mN9NZU9uJHQ

Most noticeable is the red colour, on the import statements.

When my charger plugs in it gets a little brighter, as if it's suddenly a bolded font.

It's different to upping the brightness of my screen because nothing else changes.

What's causing this?

Comment: Despite the brightness remaining visually the same, I suspect that the difference is due to the same mechanism that adjusts brightness when adapter is plugged/unplugged.  Ensure in both GUI and CLI that the brightness is set to remain the same.  Secondary possibility : In the past, MacBooks were sold with both a discrete GPU and an integrated CPU/GPU.  What model of MacBook is this?

Comment: @ChristopherHostage idk if the brightness does remain visually the same, the red definitely pops more (the blue more subtly) when it is plugged in